# Meaning of "just past"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of "just past" in this sentence:

> We’re a small community in the forest; people say that no roads lead here, **just past**.

Answer (score 3):

‘just’ here means ‘only’.  Roads go *past* the village, but not *to* it.  It's a colorful way of saying that, of the people who use the road, practically none stop at the village.

(Added) The meaning of *past* is ambiguous.  Most commenters take it to mean that the road bypasses the village.  I choose instead to read *past* as ‘beyond’: the road may happen to go through the village, but it was not made for the village; no one using the road is going *to* the village, they're all going beyond it.  (Added also) My reading is supported by the phrase “people say”, which does not normally introduce a statement of literal and readily-confirmed fact.

Comment: If the roads pass by a village, then how does it mean different from that no roads lead to that village?

Comment: It means some roads may come near, but they don't actually enter the community.

Comment: The writer chose to say it this way to make a point. There are roads near the village, but the village is so unimportant that nobody bothered to connect them to the village. Why? Because very few people go to the village! It's way more interesting and descriptive than just saying "No roads lead to the village".